# Symfony - Configuration values vs parameters

Tags: symfony

It's been a while i use Symfony (2/3) now, and i'v always asked myself despite reading almost the complete documentation:

Why would configuration values not be available as parameters straight aways (to inject in services, etc) ? For instance if i have a `config.yml` like

```
namespace_bundle:
  universe:
    answer: 42
```

... why cant' i inject a parameter in some service `%namespace_bundle.universe.answer%` (since Sf has a nice `PropertyAccess` component)

This always forced me te define parameters from the config in *BundleExtension. What is the design idea behind this ?

Or maybe i've been missing something for years ?...

Comment: Parsing the config can do much more than creating parameters : creating services for instance

Comment: All right but why not be able to inject config values as parameters out of the box ??

Comment: I can't speak for the original designers but I always thought of these as being private to the namespace_bundle.  You don't particularly want external developers to have direct access to them in the same way that class private/protected keywords restrict access to classes.  Explicitly creating a parameter basically makes the value public.